# ¿Como hacer una conexion a SQL SERVER con php desde un servidor web?

Tags: php, sql-server, windows-server

Tengo el siguiente error:

```
   Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -49 [code] 
=> 
  -49 [2] => This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 or 13 for 
SQL 
Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 or 13 for 
SQL 
Server for x64: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 [message] => 
This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 or 13 for SQL Server. 
Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 or 13 for SQL Server 
for x64: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 ) [1] => Array ( [0] 
=> 
 IM002 [SQLSTATE] => IM002 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [unixODBC][Driver 
 Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified 
 [message] 
 => [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default 
driver 
 specified ) )`
```

pero al momento de hacerlo de modo local en xammp no hay problema, ya hice publica la ip del servidor donde se aloja la base de datos y nada me sale el mismo error, quisiera saber si alguno sabe como hacerlo? GRACIAS

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Tenes instalado el driver de conexion en tu servidor web? porque l error dice que falta eso...

Comment: Necesitas tener el controlador ODBC 11 instalado en tu máquina. puedes obtenerlo desde aqui [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434)

Comment: si tengo instalado el odbc 11 en el servidor de la base de datos y en el servidor web la extencion sqlsrv esta habilitada.